# College Result Processing System Database Normalization

Tags: mysql, many-to-many, database-normalization

Hi I am in initial phase of Developing College Result Processing System So far I have developed these tables and I am confuse is it normalized or not?.[image]

here are sample data for the tables

```
**levels**
id | name
1  | Bachelor degree
2  | Masters degree

**faculties**
id | name
1  | management
2  | science and technology
3  | humanities and social science

**courses**
id | name                  | level_id | faculty_id
1  | Rural Development(RD) | 1        | 3
2  | Computer Science      | 1        | 2

**subjects**
id | name  | code
1  | sub1  | RD401
2  | sub2  | CS321
3  | sub3  | RD402

**semesters**
id | name  |
1  | sem1  |
2  | sem2  |

**course_subject**
course_id | subject_id | semester_id
1         | 1          | 1
2         | 3          | 1
```

**opt_subjects** table is for optional subjects. My doubt is in table **course_subject** which is pivot table of many-to-many relation of tables course and subject with extra field semester_id. Is there any other way to do this.
Thank you for your any help and suggestions.

Comment: You're not asking a clear question. Can you specify what you're concerned about?

Comment: thanks my main question is about normalization and about the extra field (semester_id) in  table course_subject - is there any other way to handle semester wise course subjects

Comment: Whether a database schema is normalised or not, it is not a yes or no question, since there are different normal forms. As to the other question, it depends on if the same subject can be taken in different semester during a course or not.

Comment: What about "normalization"? What do you think that means? What reference are you using for it? What does " for optional subjects" mean? What is in opt_subjects? "Another way to do" what? You are not clear.

Comment: It's normalised, but it's not necessarily correct. One might expect a subject to belong to a course regardless of which semester it took place within.